# Google Maps Searchbar in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, searchbar

Is the Searchbar in google apps such as Gmail, Goole Maps an AppBar with integrated Searchbar or just a Searchbar put on top of the rest of the body?

I'm trying to implement something like that with Flutter. Just a SearchBar on top of the rest of the screen.

```
Stack(
          children: [
            MyPage(
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: SearchBar(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

It looks fine but I don't know if it is best pratice.

This is the expected output from Google Maps

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an image of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

> Just a SearchBar on top of the rest of the screen.

while I don't see a problem using a `Stack` widget, you might want to still consider using an `AppBar` on the `Scaffold`:

```dart
 Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Card(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: '',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text('Hello World'),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[image]